# How to simplify context free grammars?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

How to simplify this context-free grammar? 
$$
S \to ACD \\ A \to a \\ B \to \varepsilon \\ C \to ED \mid \varepsilon \\ D \to BC \mid b \\E \to b
$$

Can the simplification result in this CFG?

$$
S \to AC \\ S \to A \\ A \to a \\ C \to E \\ E \to b
$$

Comment: The language generated by the new grammar is $\{a,ab\}$. The old grammar can generate other words, such as $abbb$.

Comment: that's what I was thinking. The languages of each grammar are not equivalent but this example is in automata theory lectures I was checking if there's a mistake. @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Anyway how can we simplify this CFG @YuvalFilmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting point:
$$
S \to ACD \\ A \to a \\ B \to \varepsilon \\ C \to ED \mid \varepsilon \\ D \to BC \mid b \\E \to b
$$
Substitute values of $A,B,E$:
$$
S \to aCD \\ C \to bD \mid \varepsilon \\ D \to C \mid b
$$
Substitute values of $D$:
$$
S \to aCC \mid aCb \\ C \to bC \mid bb \mid \varepsilon
$$
You can generate $bb$ from $C$ even without the rule $C \to bb$:
$$
S \to aCC \mid aCb \\ C \to bC \mid \varepsilon
$$
You can generate $b$ from $C$:
$$
S \to aCC \\ C \to bC \mid \varepsilon
$$
The language of $C$ is $b^*$, so $CC$ generates exactly the same words as $C$:
$$
S \to aC \\ C \to bC \mid \varepsilon
$$

---

The grammar generates the regular language $ab^*$.

Comment: thank you very much. That is so helpful , but if I was asked just to remove epsilon-productions how can I do that?

Comment: You follow the algorithm for removing $\epsilon$-productions.

Comment: would the result be something like this: S-->A|AC|AD|ACD    A-->a    C-->E|ED   D-->C|b    E-->b

Comment: Just apply the algorithm. I'm not going to check that you applied it correctly.